# Feign client OAuth2 grant type password

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a service I want to access using Feign client. The problem is that it requires authorization using `OAuth2, password` (as said in the `Authorize` page of Swagger and `flow: password` is set).

In the `Swagger` page of the service I can get the access to the methods by simply clicking on the `Authorize` and inputing my `login` and `password`, choosing `request body` and leaving `client_id` and `client_secret` fields as they were default, but how do I do that using Feign client now?

I tried following this [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-feign-oauth-token) but it describes how to do it with grant type `client_credentials` so it didn't work for me, it was expectedly giving errors and not accesing the method of the service. I checked the api of the service just to be sure, grant type is in fact `password`. When sending a request it was doing it with "Bearer null".

```
feign.FeignException$Unauthorized: [401] during [GET] to [...] [TestFeignClient#req(String)]: [{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Cannot convert access token to JSON"}]
```

There's a lot of code I don't know about, so I tried to find another guide which will be about grant type `password`. I tried to follow [this guide](https://piotrminkowski.com/2017/12/01/microservices-security-with-spring-cloud-oauth2/) which suits my situation, but Maven gives me errors about these dependencies, so the code is all red too (I checked the source code of the guide which can be found [here](https://github.com/piomin/sample-spring-oauth2-microservices/tree/master)
to find the dependencies, it's in the `customer` package pom, on the branch `with_database` as the author said in the comments section):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

So my question is: how can I correctly implement OAuth2 password grant type with Feign client? Is there any actual guides on how to do it? Becasue I didn't find any except these 2 and they both didn't work out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, you need to add this dependency I didn't notice in order to not to specify versions of dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Edgware.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Or just specify versions of the dependencies (second guide).

Answer (score 0):

Grant type "password" would mean that your resource server sends userid and password to the authentication server (oauth 2 server). This would mean you would send data tied to an actual user of your application over the wire. This is not something you want do anymore and this grant type is deprecated.

When you say you input client id and client secret in swagger, you are actually using grant type "client credentials" and not grant type "password". The data you are sending "over the wire" identifies an application or client, hence CLIENT id and CLIENT secret.

The userid and password you are entering is not sent to the authorization server. It might be some kind of BASIC authentication you have in front of your swagger mask.

Stick to your Bealdung guide, its exactly what you want to do. Setup all the beans you can see under 4.2 and provide the needed configuration. Afterwards you should be able to autowire the configured feignclient bean and use it anywhere.

Comment: As I said it didn't work out, I followed the guide, I think these fields in the swagger just don't do nothing because I left them as default, so you can forget about them, I need grant_type password.

Comment: I edited the question and added the error it was giving with Baeldung guide.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would also post the code and the properties you used when you received the 401-response.

Comment: exactly as in guide, that's why I didn't add it, you think it can affect it somehow?

Comment: Try and debug your code to understand what is actually happening and most importantly check the value of the "Authorization" header. It's value should look like "Bearer xxxxxxx". When i look at the exception you posted it seems like your authorization header might be "broken"

Comment: yes, checked it, it was null when exception occured